# How on earth I am supposed to find an expression for C1 from this?

Tags: logarithms, systems-of-equations, puzzle, economics

I am currently studing economics and I encountered this problem that is driving me crazy.
I need to solve for C1 from this set of equations:

$\frac{1}{C_1}= \frac{p}{C_2^h}+\frac{q}{C_2^m}+\frac{z}{C_2^l}$

$C_2^h=Y_2^h+(1+r)Y_1-(1+r)C_1$

$C_2^m=Y_2^m+(1+r)Y_1-(1+r)C_1$

$C_2^l=Y_2^l+(1+r)Y_1-(1+r)C_1$

The first one is the Euler equation from an optimization problem with unincertainty on the output of the second period. Then, $p+q+z=1$ because they are the probabilities assigned to each state. The heading also mentionates that:

$Y_1=E \left\{ Y_2 \right\}$

I managed to get to:

$C_2^hC_2^mC_2^l=pC_1C_2^mC_2^l+qC_1C_2^hC_2^l+zC_1C_2^hC_2^m$

Also I tried to open that equation and replace the C2 but it was effort wasted.

Hope someone out there has an answer to this puzzle (or maybe has already faced this problem in the past and knows the key to solve it)

Thx in advance.
Greetings from Argentina.

Comment: "*I need to clear $C_1$*" $\;-\;$ Please clarify what "*clear*" means here - whether "*eliminate*" $C_1$ between the equations, or "*solve*" the system for $C_1$.

Comment: Sorry, i mean solve the system for C1.

Comment: You have a lot of variables and symbols that haven’t been declared. For example, what does $h$ means in $Y_2^h$? Is it some kind if tensor index?

Comment: Yes, it is an index. The problem has three posible outcomes for Y2: Y2h (high income), Y2m (medium income) and y2l (low income). p, q and z are their probabilities respectively.

Comment: @LuccaF Substitute $C_2^{h,m,l}$ from the last three equations in the first one, eliminate the denominators, then you get a cubic equation in $C_1$ alone. Cubics are solvable by radicals, though the solution won't necessarily be "nice" unless there are additional relations between the other variables.

Comment: Thanks dxiv. I gonna try that way.